# Tkinter ScrolledFrame initial dimensions

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using [PWM ScrolledFrame](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/ScrolledFrame.html) and I'd like to make its size smaller than the default size. I don't want to use the fixed size (the `usehullsize=1` option).

Here is what I tried:

```
import Tkinter
import Pmw

root = Tkinter.Tk()
Pmw.initialise(root)

sf = ScrolledFrame(root)
sf.interior().configure(height=50, width=50, bg='yellow')
sf.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But it results in this:

[image]

The clipper frame is obviously unaffected by the configured size of the interior frame. Can I access the clipper frame somehow to configure its size as well?

Comment: See http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/howtouse.html , and the 'Components' section in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the following line after `sf = ScrolledFrame(root)`:

```
sf._clipper.config(width='value_you_want', height='value_you_want')
```

A complete example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

import tkinter
import Pmw

root = tkinter.Tk()
Pmw.initialise(root)

sf = Pmw.ScrolledFrame(root)
sf._clipper.config(width=100, height = 200)
sf.interior().configure(height=80, width=80, bg='yellow')

sf.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

with the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just saying, I have never used this before. But surely is it not just this part that you linked in your question?

```
self.sf = Pmw.ScrolledFrame(parent,
            labelpos = 'n', label_text = 'ScrolledFrame',
            usehullsize = 1,
            hull_width = 400,
            hull_height = 220,
    )
```

the hull_width, and height?

Comment: Those settings work, but they impose fixed size on the ScrolledFrame. I'd like to keep the frame size dynamic.